# use of auto in range based for loops to iterate over string

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

consider following program

```
string hr = "hackerrank";
for(auto &c: hr){
        cout<<c;
}
```

this code runs perfectly fine on hackerrank but whenever I try to compile this program on my ubuntu 16.4.1 using g++ compiler, it shows following error,

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘c’ with no type [-fpermissive]
for(auto &c: hr){
```

why is it showing error on g++ compiler but not on HackerRank ?

PS: I tried going through all questions where this error is discussed. but I couldn't find an answer. If you find a similar question then let me know.

Comment: What version of `g++` are you using?

Comment: What is the command line you're using to compile with `g++`? Are you sure you're specifying `c++11` or later?

Comment: I am using gcc 5.4.0. Command used to compile the program was `g++ filename.cpp`

Comment: Add -std=c++11 to your command

Comment: @manni66 .. It worked !